# converting to date format character

Tags: r

if haven been trying to use as.Date()
my original data is

Out-put of original data

data.frame':    3650 obs. of  2 evariables:
$ Date                      : chr  "01-01-1981" "01-02-1981" "01-03-1981" "01-04-1981" ...
$ Daily.minimum.temperatures: num  20.7 17.9 18.8 14.6 15.8 15.8 15.8 17.4 21.8 20 ...

here the date is in  character need to convert into proper date format

when using the above code

```
temp2$date2<-as.Date(temp2$date,format = "%d/%m/%Y-%u")
```

### output

```
> temp2$date2<-as.Date(temp2$date,format = "%d/%b/%Y-%u")
```

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, date2, value = numeric(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 3650

How to rectify the error

Comment: `temp2$date2<-as.Date(temp2$date,format = "%d-%m-%Y")`

Comment: @ Ronak still getting the same error

Comment: Can you provide the data using `dput` ?  output of `dput(head(temp2))` would be helpful.